# How to return properly in if else and avoid "void" for errors about return

Tags: java, methods, return

I am having a hard time how to return into specific variable or how to return without getting any error base on my program.

```
class Facebook {
    public static void main(String[]args){      

        String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Username: ");

        String pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Password: ");

        if(user.equals("jas")&&(pass.equals("bsit"))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome "+ user);
            Selection Class = new Selection();
            Selection.Selection1();
        }

        else if (!user.equals("jas")||(!pass.equals("bsit"))) { 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Invalid Username or Password",
                "Wrong Authentication",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);


        }

    }
}

class Selection{
    public Selection1(){

        try{
            String select = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("[1]Home\n[2]Profile\n[3]Logout");
            int numbers = Integer.parseInt(select);

            if (numbers == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mang Tani: Lumakas ang hanging amihan halos nilipad ang mga bubong ng mga bahay\n\nJessica Soho: Isang sikat na pagkain sa davao inubos ng kabataan \n\n Boying Remulla: Walang pasok dahil sa malakas na ulan\n#WalangPasok.");
                return select;
            }
            else if (numbers == 2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: Ralph Jasper \n\n Age: 17 \n\n Address: Tierra Nevada, General Trias, Cavite");

            }
            else if (numbers == 3){

            }

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please input only numbers","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: You can't put a `Selection1` constructor in a class named `Selection`.

Comment: When you have a return type, you can never reach a state where you end up never using `return`. In your case I see 3 different cases where it would happen (an exception, or `if` statements 2/3)

Comment: thanks ... but any idea how to work return with that code?

Comment: Selection Class = new Selection();  DAFUK?

Comment: just learning dude -_-

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you want a method with a return value of a string

Replace

```
public Selection1(){
```

with

```
public String select()
```

2) all  "paths" of a non-void method must result in a return statement. This does not mean a return statement needs to be inside any if else's, but you do need to return something within the method.

Suggestion: declare a `String result = "";` outside of the try catch, return it after, outside of the catch, and assign it to your JOptionPane value in between like `result = JOptionPane...`

3) I'm assuming you actually want that value that's returned?

```
Selection selector = new Selection();
String selected = selector.select();
// TODO use that value
```

Notice: Java naming conventions -- methods are `lowerCase`, classes are `UpperCase`.

Comment: Thanks so much ! you just save my night ^_^ i just learned return

Comment: But still im still having some problem

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @JhasJhas Replace `String select =  ` with `result = `

Comment: okay next time just need to wait 90 min before i need to do it again thanks

Comment: Please delete your non-answer below since it does not actually answer the question and introduces other errors.